# How to Dynamically AutoFill Destination using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have two Tables Table1 & Table2.
Table1 has a manual input in Column C which updates other columns on that table.
Table2 relies on that manual input to AutoFill all its' Table Values.

**Data Example:**
[image]

How do you dynamically update Table2? Both tables change so much that I have Dynamic Ranges which reference the last Rows of each table.

I have the following code and it's just one line that I have having issues with because it errors out.

```
Sub Auto_Fill()
 
    ' Auto_Fill Macro
      
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[U/C LEVEL]]").End(xlDown).Select
      
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
      
        Range("Table3[#Headers]").End(xlDown).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(**THIS IS THE BIT I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH**), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("Table3[[#Headers],[HEIGHT DIFF.]]").End(xlDown).Select
      
    End If
      
End Sub
```

I don't know how to finish this:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(THIS IS THE BIT I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I want to find the last value in Column C in Table1 and if not empty I want to find the last row of Table2 and AutoFill the Table2 row down one row with all the formulas and values currently in Table2.

I tried about 20 links. None of the combinations of solutions seem to work with my particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to autofill Table3, try...

```
Dim lastListRow As ListRow

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")
    Set lastListRow = .ListRows(.ListRows.Count)
End With

With lastListRow
    .Range.AutoFill Destination:=.Range.Resize(2), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

Comment: That was super helpful! Thank you very much. I do have another question on this... How do you make the Resize format dynamic? Is this possible without setting it to a specific number and it is reliant on Table 3?

Comment: That's great, glad I could help!  With regards to your follow-up question, though, can you please explain how you want the resizing reliant on Table3?